# Get feature of point shapefile for WMS created in GeoServer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I created a WMS from a polygon shapefile in GeoServer and next I created a WMS  from a point shapefile. Then I wrote  HTML code that add WMS polygon and shapefile on a base map and that is done, but I want when I click to each point of point shapefile it returns feature of that point to me in a pop up.

I wrote a function but it doesn't work. I wrote these HTML code and JavaScript code:

html code:

```
      <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" type="text/css" crossorigin="">
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
            
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>


<body>
<div class="board"></div>
    <div class="board1"></div>




 <div id="map">  

 </div>
 
<div id="top">
         <FORM style='font-size:10px'><i class='fas fa-arrow-up'></i><INPUT type="button" id="top1" name="button1" onClick="top2();"></FORM>
    </div>
    
    <div id="left">
        <FORM style='font-size:10px'> <i class='fas fa-arrow-left'></i><INPUT type="button" id="left1"  name="button1" onClick="left2();"></FORM>
    </div>
    
    <div id="right">
        <FORM style='font-size:10px'> <i class='fas fa-arrow-right'></i> <INPUT type="button" id="right1"  name="button1" onClick="right2();"></FORM>
    </div>
    
    <div id="button11">
        <FORM style='font-size:10px'> <i class='fas fa-arrow-down'></i><INPUT  type="button" id="botton111" name="button1" onClick="button2() ;"></FORM>
    </div>
    
    <div id="zoomin" onClick="zoomin2();">
    <button id="zoomin1" style='font-size:16px'><i class='fas fa-search-plus'></i></button> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="zoomout" onClick="zoomout2() ;">
    <button id="zoomout1" style='font-size:16px'><i class='fas fa-search-minus'></i>
       <!-- <FORM><INPUT  type="button" id="zoomout1" name="button1" value="-" onClick="zoomout2() ;"></FORM>-->
    </div>  
    
    <div id="zoomextend" onClick="zoomextend2() ;">
    <button id="zoomextend1" style="font-size:15px"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/zoom-to-extents.png" height = "25px"></i></button>
       <!-- <FORM style="font-size:24px"> <i class="material-icons"></i><INPUT  type="button"  id="zoomextend1" name="button1" onClick="zoomextend2() ;"></FORM>-->
    </div>


<h1 id="title">Iran Villages</h1>
          <div id="mapid">
          </div>
          <div id="docs">
              
          </div>


    

</body>


<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            

</html>
```

css code:

```
        position: fixed;
    left: 325px;
    top: 10px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #6f0d809c;
    height: 325px;
    width: 654px;
}

#pan {
    position: fixed;
    top: 357px;
    left: 327px;
    width: 86px;
    height: 88px;
    z-index: -2;
}

#top1 {border-color: #d5bada;
    background-color: #a763b3;
    border-style: outset;
    height: 28px;
    width: 18px;
    z-index: -1;
   left: 359px;
    top: 350px;
    position: fixed;
       
}
#left1 {     top: 378px;
    width: 28px;
    left: 329px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 18px;
    border-style: outset;
    background-color: #a763b3;
    border-color: #d5bada;  
}
    
#right1{
          top: 3px;
    width: 28px;
    left: -24px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 18px;
    border-style: outset;
    background-color: #a763b3;
    border-color: #d5bada;
    
}

#botton111
 {
    border-color: #d5bada;
    background-color: #a763b3;
    border-style: outset;
    height: 28px;
    width: 18px;
    z-index: -1;
   top: 397px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 359px;
}
#top{    left: 362px;
    top: 353px;
    position: fixed;

}
#left {    position: fixed;
    top: 380px;
    left: 333px;
}
#right{
position: fixed;
    left: 389px;
    top: 375px
}
#button11 {left: 363px;
    top: 405px;
    position: fixed;
}
#zoomin {
}

#zoomout {
}

#zoomextend {
    
}

#zoomin1 {left: 448px;
    top: 378px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 27px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #b47dbd;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

#zoomout1 {

left: 504px;
    top: 378px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 27px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #b47dbd;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
    
#zoomextend1 {left: 560px;
    top: 378px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 27px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #b47dbd;
    border-radius: 7px;
    z-index:-1;
    
}
```

js code:

```
var target1 = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ratio: 1,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wmsIran/wms',
          params: {
                   'VERSION':'1.1.0',
                   LAYERS:'wmsIran:Ostan',
                   serverType:'geoserver',

                   }

        })
});
      
var target5 = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ratio: 1,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/noghat/wms',
          params: {
                   'VERSION':'1.1.0',
                   LAYERS:'noghat:Village',

                   }

        })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        target1,
        target5
        ], 
view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([53,33]),
        zoom:4.5
        }),
controls:[],   
});

function Identify(e)
              {
                // set parameters needed for GetFeatureInfo WMS request
                var sw = map.options.crs.project(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
                var ne = map.options.crs.project(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
                var BBOX = sw.x + "," + sw.y + "," + ne.x + "," + ne.y;
                var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
                var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;

                var X = Math.trunc(map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x);
                var Y = Math.trunc(map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y);

                // compose the URL for the request
                var URL = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/noghat/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=noghat:Village&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson'
                //send GetFeatureInfo as asynchronous HTTP request using jQuery $.ajax

                $.ajax({
                   url: URL,
                   dataType: "json",
                   type: "GET",
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                     if(data.features.length !== 0) {  // at least one feature returned in response
                       var returnedFeature = data.features[0]; // first feature from response

                       // Set up popup for clicked feature and open it
                       var popup = new L.Popup({
                         maxWidth: 300
                       });

                       popup.setContent("<b>" + returnedFeature.properties.NAME + "</b><br />" + returnedFeature.properties.ADDRESS);
                       popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
                       map.openPopup(popup);
                        }
                      }
                     });
                }

map.addEventListener('click', Identify);

var center=map.getView().getCenter();


var newcenter=center;
function top2(){
    newcenter=[newcenter[0],newcenter[1]+1000];
    map.getView().setCenter(newcenter);
}
    


function left2(){
     newcenter=[newcenter[0]-1000,newcenter[1]];
     map.getView().setCenter(newcenter);
}


function right2(){
     newcenter=[newcenter[0]+1000,newcenter[1]];
     map.getView().setCenter(newcenter);
}

function button2(){ 
     newcenter=[newcenter[0],newcenter[1]-1000];
     map.getView().setCenter(newcenter);
}


var zoom=map.getView().getZoom();
var newzoom=zoom;

 function zoomin2(){
     newzoom=newzoom+1;
     map.getView().setZoom(newzoom);
 }
 
function zoomout2(){
     newzoom=newzoom-1;
     map.getView().setZoom(newzoom);
 }
 
  function zoomextend2(){
     newcenter=center;
     newzoom=zoom;
     map.getView().setCenter(newcenter);
     map.getView().setZoom(newzoom);
 }
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: You cannot use OpenLayers 2 or Leaflet methods on an OpenLayers 3+ map.  Nor can you rely on map size as OpenLayers buffers the WMS layer to avoid continuous reloads while panning.  You can get the correct url for an info request by using the getFeatureInfoUrl method as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html

Comment: You have a lot of code that doesn't seem relevant to the question, not sure you need all that css and HTML to describe your JavaScript issue.    You don't actually say what issue you have with the GetFeatureInfo popup.  You talk about WMS, but the JS has a WFS request in it, how is that relevant?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works